# Any effective way to count web application traffic when testing locally?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am writing a GWT web application which is supposed to run on Google App Engine. I an working in Eclipse and using the plug-in supplied by Google. Now I was wondering if there is any effective way to count the traffic when testing the application.

Comment: What do you mean with counting the traffic? Do you mean to measure how much inbound and outbound data the application generates?

Comment: @tomlog I want to measure the network traffic. The goal is to count average network traffic of the website (in bytes) per user visit. The application does bunch of RPC requests, etc.

Comment: You could use Wireshark and filter your capture to whatever port the dev server is running on.

Comment: @Drew Sears hehe I guess that will work, didn't think about it. Thanks a lot!